# Angular 5 passing a value to an attribute

Tags: angular

what is the equivalent of {{obj.firstname}} for an html attribute value...?

This works: `<label for="obj"> {{obj.param_meta}} </label>` but when applied to an attribute it does not.

```
<input for="obj" type="text" formControlName="obj.param_meta">
```

**ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'obj.param_meta'**

Adding bracket works but I still get error for it in the console log.

```
<input for="obj" type="text" [formControlName]="obj.param_meta">
```

**ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'NAME'**

Comment: It means that your FormGroup doesn't have control with the name `NAME`

Comment: share your componen.ts code

Comment: @yurzui thanks I'll look at my FormGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen examples which uses dynamic `formControlName` directive. Instead try to bind a `formControl` like this:

```
<input for="obj" type="text" [formControl]="form.get(obj.param_meta)">
```

Comment: If you have never seen such examples with `[formControlName]` then you can start with Angular docs https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form. I would say it's common case for dynamic forms

Comment: @yurzui Haven't been to the official docs since the Beta hehe.